# Keep headers after dataframe transformation

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I'm working with sklearn and pandas with some microarrays, and I have a pandas DataFrame with every column named. So I'm doing some transformations to the dataframe, essentially feature selection.

```
data = pd.read_csv("data.txt")
print(data)
```

Resulting in

```
    1007_s_at  1053_at       ...         AFFX-TrpnX-5_at  AFFX-TrpnX-M_at
0     3.96932  2.52634       ...                 2.09691          1.99123
1     4.10452  2.43457       ...                 2.28103          2.06446
2     3.95308  2.36736       ...                 2.11059          1.80618
3     3.99712  2.55388       ...                 2.13354          1.91908
4     3.95279  2.21484       ...                 2.22531          2.03342
..        ...      ...       ...                     ...              ...
96    3.79560  2.74194       ...                 2.01703          2.03743
97    3.79817  2.47422       ...                 2.12385          2.07188
98    3.84186  2.59329       ...                 2.16435          1.69897

[99 rows x 22283 columns]
```

As we can see, every column has a name.

Then I'm removing some columns with the VarianceThreshold method

```
data = VarianceThreshold(0.04).fit_transform(data)
print(data)
print("After Variance Threshold data shape: ", data.shape)
```

So the new data looks like

```
[[4.1835  2.20952 2.41664 ... 2.21748 2.69197 2.41996]
 [3.82478 2.2878  1.69897 ... 1.87506 2.09691 2.35411]
 [4.1503  2.32015 2.35793 ... 2.01284 2.2833  2.15534]
 ...
 [3.85576 3.26694 2.71684 ... 2.68305 3.18298 2.83378]
 [3.25912 2.04922 2.58092 ... 2.0607  2.66932 2.42325]
 [3.34044 2.24551 2.60097 ... 2.03743 2.31806 2.35984]]
After Variance Threshold data shape:  (99, 5002)
```

Now, data is a numpy array and I've lost the headers of every column that remains from the original dataframe.

Is there any way to keep them with pandas/numpy?

Comment: Numpy arrays don't have headers. Considering we cannot see _any_ of the steps you took to transform the data and switched between arrays and dataframes, it's impossible to make any suggestions. Please give an [mcve]

Comment: @roganjosh I edited the post and added some more information

Comment: 22283 columns to 5002, how can it keep column names?

Comment: @AndyHayden I don't understand what you are trying to say

Comment: how can you "keep the headers" when there's fewer headers

Comment: @AndyHayden But I need to keep the header of the columns that weren't removed. So you're saying that there isn't any way to do it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`get_support`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.VarianceThreshold.html#sklearn.feature_selection.VarianceThreshold.get_support) to get a mask rather than the result:

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 2, 0, 3], [0, 1, 4, 3], [0, 1, 1, 3]], columns=list("ABCD"))

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
   A  B  C  D
0  0  2  0  3
1  0  1  4  3
2  0  1  1  3

In [13]: VarianceThreshold().fit(df).get_support()
Out[13]: array([False,  True,  True, False])

In [14]: df.loc[:, VarianceThreshold().fit(df).get_support()]
Out[14]:
   B  C
0  2  0
1  1  4
2  1  1
```

In your example:

```
df.loc[:, VarianceThreshold(0.04).fit(data).get_support()]
```

Comment: Beautiful answer Andy. Although in "your example" part, it would be data.loc[:, VarianceThreshold(0.04).fit(data).get_support()]. That worked like a charm. Thank you so much.